# in my silverlight app i am finding this error .Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component

Tags: silverlight

**in my silverlight app i am finding this error when i am trying to assign itemssource to listbox .Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component**

at MS.Internal.XcpImports.CheckHResult(UInt32 hr)
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.SetValue(IManagedPeerBase obj, DependencyProperty property, Boolean b)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValue(DependencyProperty property, Boolean b)
   at System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl.ClearContainers(Boolean bHostIsReplaced)
   at System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl.ItemsSourceChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.RaisePropertyChangeNotifications(DependencyProperty dp, Object oldValue, Object newValue)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(DependencyProperty property, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, ValueOperation operation)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueInternal(DependencyProperty dp, Object value, Boolean allowReadOnlySet, Boolean isBindingInStyleSetter)
   at System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl.set_ItemsSource(IEnumerable value)
   at HRPMS.MyDesk.ConferenceRoomBooking.AddSourceToListBox()
   at HRPMS.MyDesk.ConferenceRoomBooking.chkbxCCConsultant_Unchecked(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ToggleButton.OnUnchecked(RoutedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ToggleButton.OnIsCheckedPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.RaisePropertyChangeNotifications(DependencyProperty dp, Object oldValue, Object newValue)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(DependencyProperty property, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, ValueOperation operation)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.RefreshExpression(DependencyProperty dp)
   at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.SendDataToTarget()
   at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.SourcePropertyChanged(PropertyPathListener sender, PropertyPathChangedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.PropertyPathListener.ReconnectPath()
   at System.Windows.Data.Debugging.BindingBreakPoint.<>c__DisplayClass4.b__3()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this a dozen times, if I remember correctly it usually occurred when there is a problem in the xaml of a `View` or `Template` the very moment it is instantiated or switched to visible (or a `VisualState` change is triggered).

Good candidates are:

- references to `StaticResources` that cannot be found
- VisualState change and a Target cannot be found, or a StaticResource cannot be found, or the new `Value` for a `DiscreteObjectKeyFrame` cannot be translated to the target type

for the last point compare these two, had this quite often:

```
<DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="True"/>
```

versus

```
<DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0">
    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
        <System:Boolean>True</System:Boolean>
    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
</DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
```