# Exception - "Value does not fall within the expected range.inPage.xaml"

Tags: silverlight, exception, windows-phone-8, asynchronous, mvvmcross

I create app on Windows Phone 8 use MVVMCross and async Sqlite.net. Sometimes when you go to a page I get an exception:

```
System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.inPage.xaml'.
at System.Windows.Navigation.PageResourceContentLoader.EndLoad(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationService.ContentLoader_BeginLoad_Callback(IAsyncResult result)
at System.Windows.Navigation.PageResourceContentLoader.BeginLoad_OnUIThread(AsyncCallback userCallback, PageResourceContentLoaderAsyncResult result)
at System.Windows.Navigation.PageResourceContentLoader.<>c__DisplayClass4.<BeginLoad>b__0(Object args)
```

How do I determine the source of the problem?

Comment: The page resource content loader, I believe, is responsible for loading a resource dictionary. It seems you have an error or erroneous value in one of your resource dictionaries.

Comment: This error occurs rarely.

Answer (score 0):

Had those errors too. Usually it was a `VisualState` value that could not be converted.
I copied the example from [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26647848/1280867)

```
<DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="True"/>
```

versus

```
<DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0">
    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
        <System:Boolean>True</System:Boolean>
    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
</DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
```

So when you say it does not happen every time it may for example be happening only when coincidentally you hover your mouse over a certain area and the problem sits somewhere in a mouseover state definition.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in my xaml. I used this user control:

```
  <UserControl>
       <controls:Pivot >
        <controls:PivotItem >
            <UserControl2/>
        </controls:PivotItem>
        <controls:PivotItem >
            <UserControl2/>
        </controls:PivotItem>
    </controls:Pivot>
<UserControl>
```

I removed Pivot and error disappeared.